# Can't upload a file on Messenger bot with Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, curl, facebook-messenger, messenger

I can't upload an image with [Messenger bot](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/image-attachment) on Ruby.

Here is a code that works in Bash:

```
curl  \
  -F recipient='{"id":"USER_ID"}' \
  -F message='{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F filedata="@out.jpg" \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS"
```

Here is a translation with RestClient:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

file = "out.jpg"
tkn = "PAGE_ACCESS"
params = {
    "recipient" => {"id" => "USER_ID"},
    "message"   => {
        "attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}
    },
    "filedata" => 'out.jpg'
}
puts params.to_json
begin
    r = RestClient.post "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=#{tkn}", params.to_json, :content_type => :json
rescue => e
    puts e.response
end
```

Here is the answer I get:

```
{"recipient":{"id":"USER_ID"},"message":{"attachment":{"type":"image","payload":{}}},"filedata":"@out.jpg"}
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Incorrect number of files uploaded. Must upload exactly one file.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"xxxxx"}}
```

Comment: I prefer not using the gem Curb to respect the architecture in which it will be

Comment: I am also banging my head against this problem, any insight would be welcome :/

Comment: Well at the end of the day, I just did a bash command inside Ruby. Far from a nice result, but it is working.

Comment: I figured it out, albeit using Node.js as my server side lang. I know nothing of Ruby, but the gist of the problem was that FB messenger api expects a MULTIPART upload with the file as a stream (that's what the -F parameter in curl does).